# C++ - Is there a way to print out a comma if only when there's another output printed after the comma itself?

Tags: c++, for-loop, printing

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will only print a comma after an output if there is another output printed out after it. I use

```
  for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
       {
          if(price[i][j] > 0)
          {
             cout << airports[j] << ", ";
          }
                  
       }
```

The problem is I don't know how to get rid of the last comma that is added with the last entry in the list. It outputs this:

```
Airports' destinations: 

BUR (3): LAX, SFO, SMO, 
LAX (1): BUR, 
SFO (2): BUR, SMO, 
SMO (2): BUR, SFO,
```

How do I remove the comma at the end of every output?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j = 0, comma = false; j < size; j++)
{
    if (price[i][j] > 0)
    {
        if (comma)
            cout << ", ";
        cout << airports[j];
        comma = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: I'm confused about the boolean within the for loop. Is it possible to initializes another variable other than j?

Comment: [for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for), look at *init-statement*.

Comment: The `init-statement` for a `for` loop can't declare multiple variables of *different* types, like this code is trying to do. You will have to move the `bool` outside of the loop instead: `bool comma = false; for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) { if (...) { ... comma = true; } }`